# Проблема с SEO разделом на Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, seo

Всем привет. При нажатии на кнопку SEO на панели администратора.

[image: Кнопка SEO]

Окно не погружается: [image: Окно не загружается]

В консоли вываливается ошибка.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: Instance
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ((index):1), <anonymous>:1:80)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ((index):1), <anonymous>:1:19992)
    at <anonymous>:1:16084
    at Function.BX.evalGlobal (core.js?1582151489541056:18)
    at inlineScripts (core.js?1582151489541056:30)
    at core.js?1582151489541056:30
    at core.js?1582151489541056:23
    at core.js?1582151489541056:23
    at HTMLScriptElement.process (core.js?1582151489541056:23)
```

Файл core.js не трогал. Файлы сайта так же не трогал. Отключил все сжатия и объединение скриптов в админке.
Подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема  была в услуге pagespeed на хостинге.